# Is there a way to constraint a generic type to plain objects only in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Using typescript, is there a way to constraint a generic type to allow values of type object only? Not array and other types.

For eg:

```js
function check<O extends object>(ob: O): O {
  return ob
}

check({}) // should be fine
check([]) // should show error, but does not.
```

A possible real world use case:

```js
function extend<A extends object, B extends object>(a: A, b: B): A & B {
  return {
    ...a,
    ...b,
  };
}

// This is fine, return type is { x: number } & { y: string }
extend({x: 5}, {y: "str"})

// This should not be allowed
// Return type is number[] & string[]
// Accessing a property yields impossible types like number & string
extend([1,2,3], ["s", "i", "d"])

// More examples for variants which I don't want to allow
extend({}, function() {})
extend({}, new Map())
```

Comment: This is actually fun, as every array is an object too

Answer (score 6):

You can use a conditional type to add to the parameter of the parameter if `O` extends `any[]`. What you add can ensure that the call will be an error. I usually add string literal types and think of them as a custom error message:

```
function check<O extends object>(ob: O & (O extends any[] ? "NO Arrays !" : {})): O
function check<O extends object>(ob: O): O {
  return ob
}

check({}) // should be fine
check([]) // error
```

Comment: Nice one, I thought of something similar, but I didn't came up with that union type, which makes the whole thing far more elegant.

Comment: Nice, any reason why you need overloading? It seems to work fine with just the first signature without the 2nd overload

Comment: This would only work with arrays. I am trying to avoid any type that is not a plain object.

Comment: @bugs the intersection with the conditional will tend to interfere with other stuff, not for this simple example but I thought it best to keep the conditional signature separate, you can do it with just one type as well.

Comment: @sidoshi what do you mean plain object ? `object` will not allow primitives such as number or string. If you don't want class instances, I have to think about it..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir By plain objects I mean objects created using object literal: `{}` or using `new Object(){}`. Ideally, It should not allow various other things that would have `typeof` value as `object` such as functions, arrays and class instances. Sorry I was not clear enough when I asked the question.

Comment: @sidoshi That is not possible I'm afraid .. we can do some heuristic, such as allow only objects without functions, which can be a decent proxy for "no classes", since classes usually have methods. But it is imperfect as it will both allow some classes in (classes without any methods) and also deny some objects literals (those that contain functions) but it depends on your usecase if this is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I wonder if there is a way to only allow objects that have `__proto__ = {}`?
Though `{}` has the property `__proto__` set to `{}`, I am not able to use that property as a type constraint on generic.

Comment: @sidoshi typescript does not support `__proto__`, so it has no associated type (using it is an error in fact). I also thought about `constructor` but that is typed as `Function`

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of Typescript, you can use `object & Exclude<T, any[]>` to represent an object that cannot be an array.